# Not Properly Passing Data Between Views

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, message-passing

I'm trying to send text generated by the user from the AuthenticationViewController to MainProfileViewController. I'm not receiving an error report. The label just doesn't even appear in the MainProfileViewController. The outlets are correctly hooked up. Thanks for the help!

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @class MainProfileViewController;

    @interface AuthenticationViewController : UIViewController

    {
        MainProfileViewController *mainProfileViewController;
    }

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;

    @end



    #import "AuthenticationViewController.h"
    #import "MainProfileViewController.h"

    @interface AuthenticationViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation AuthenticationViewController

    @synthesize usernameTextField;

    - (IBAction)createAccount: (id)sender {
             {
                mainProfileViewController = [[MainProfileViewController alloc] init];
                mainProfileViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                mainProfileViewController.userText.text = usernameTextField.text;
                [self presentViewController:mainProfileViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
              }
    }

    @end



    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "AuthenticationViewController.h"

    @interface MainProfileViewController : UIViewController

    {
       UITextField *userText;
    }

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userText;
    @property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *textPass;

    @end




    #import "MainProfileViewController.h"
    #import "AuthenticationViewController.h"

    @interface MainProfileViewController ()

    @end

    @implementation MainProfileViewController
    @synthesize resultLabel, userText, textPass;

    - (void)viewDidLoad
{

    userText.text = textPass;
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
    @end
```

Comment: you have to pass string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, there's a few things you're doing wrong. 
First off, you're instantiating a *local* `MainProfileViewController` instead of instantiating the one that you have an ivar pointing to.

The second thing that you're doing wrong is trying to send over the view from the `AuthenticationViewController` to the `MainProfileViewController`. You shouldn't do that. Instead, pass the text itself; otherwise you are just overwriting pointers, and nothing will show up.

```
- (IBAction)createAccount: (id)sender {
    // DON'T CREATE A LOCAL VARIABLE
    // MainProfileViewController *controller = [[MainProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    mainProfileViewController = [[MainProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
    mainProfileViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

    // DON'T TRY SENDING THE VIEW OVER
    // mainProfileViewController.userText = usernameTextField;
    mainProfileViewController.userText.text = usernameTextField.text;
    [self presentViewController:mainProfileViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

edit: I suppose it's not required that you have an ivar to the new view controller you want to present... But the point is that you cannot instantiate one, and then set the parameter on the one you did not instantiate (it will be nil).

Comment: Thanks! That helped clean the code up a bit. The label appears now but it's not changing to what the user inputs in the usernameTextField. Problem?

Comment: How have you cleaned up the code? What have you changed? Are you setting anything in any of the -init, -viewDidLoad, or other methods of MainProfileViewController? What happens when you NSLog(@"%@", usernameTextField.text); ?

Comment: OK, I think you need to slow down and look at what is pointing to what, and when. Now you're using your mainProfileViewController -- that's good! Then you are setting the text on the userText -- also good! Then, in viewDidLoad (called later), you are setting the text on userText with the textPass, which you never set -- overriding the changes you made. I think going through this step by step with a debugger and examining the variables would help you out a lot.

Comment: GOT IT! THANKS SO MUCH. Telling me to stop and slow down and think helped a lot. I had to create resultLabel.text = testPass;. I was in such a rush to completing this that I didn't think things through clearly. Thanks again!

Comment: :) No problem. A lot of times things look like they should work until you really slow down take a look at what's going on. I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Check your story board and see if you connected the Outlets properly.
There should be an IBOutlet object in your view controller that you should connect in story board.

Also check if you connected the correct view controller class to the view controller in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class MainProfileViewController;

@interface AuthenticationViewController : UIViewController

{
    MainProfileViewController *mainProfileViewController;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameTextField;

@end



#import "AuthenticationViewController.h"
#import "MainProfileViewController.h"

@interface AuthenticationViewController ()

@end

@implementation AuthenticationViewController

@synthesize usernameTextField;

- (IBAction)createAccount: (id)sender {
         {
                MainProfileViewController *controller = [[MainProfileViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainProfileViewController" bundle:nil];
                controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

                mainProfileViewController.textpass = usernameTextField.text;

                [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
          }
}

@end



#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AuthenticationViewController.h"

@interface MainProfileViewController : UIViewController

{
   UITextField *userText;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *userText;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *textpass;
@end




#import "MainProfileViewController.h"
#import "AuthenticationViewController.h"

@interface MainProfileViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainProfileViewController
@synthesize resultLabel, userText;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   usertext.text=textpass;
}
@end
```

Comment: So now the label appears but it doesn't change to the text that the user sets out. Problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code on this part...

```
 - (IBAction)createAccount: (id)sender 
   {
       mainProfileViewController = [[MainProfileViewController alloc] init];
       mainProfileViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
       mainProfileViewController.userText.text = usernameTextField.text;
       [self presentViewController:mainProfileViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

Happy Coding...

Comment: That helped clean up the code a bit. The label appears now but it's not being changed to what the user enters. Problem?